# Android autocomplete Google Places suggestions taking delays too long

Tags: android, json, autocomplete, delay, google-places-api

I implemented in my app google places autocomplete on autocomplete textview.
At first when i was working on that part predictions came up on start of typing but now there is a delay after i start typing. Usually 5 seconds but sometimes over a half of minute !!!

The strange thing is that after i try autocomplete for first time(and wait that delay) and then go back and to autocomplete again the results show WITHOUT THE DELAY !!

I've run trough my code a million times but i just can't see why is that happening.
I've cleaned my project, rebooted my device and did solution on this topic:

[How to improve performance of google places autocomplete suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060152/how-to-improve-performance-of-google-places-autocomplete-suggestions)

Here is my code:

onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    actvLocations =  (AutocompleteTextViewCustom) findViewById(R.id.actvEnterLocation);

    actvLocations.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            Log.e("dialog location after text changed", "AFTER");

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String input = "";

            // get input text
            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(s.toString(), "utf-8"); // !!! check text coding for different counties !!!
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                /**
                 * activate error screen 
                 */
            }
            // set parameters for parsing
            String parameters = input + "&" + "types=geocode" + "&" + "sensor=false";

            // start places task for getting results from google
            placesTask = new PlacesTask(listenerForAutocompleteCompletedTask, "getPredictions");
            placesTask.execute(parameters);

        }

    });

    // populate listview with previously browsed locations
    ListView listviewPreviouslyBrowsedLocations = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPreviouslyBrowsedLocations);
    final ListViewAdapter adapterListview= new ListViewAdapter(context, listPreviouslyBrowsedLocations);
    listviewPreviouslyBrowsedLocations.setAdapter(adapterListview);
    listviewPreviouslyBrowsedLocations.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, int position, long arg3) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            list.add(adapterListview.getParameters(position));
            listenerForHeaderLocationChange.onLocationChangeExecuteThisMethod(list, false);
            dismiss();

        }

    });
}

OnTaskCompleted listenerForAutocompleteCompletedTask = new OnTaskCompleted() {

    @Override
    public void onGetAutocompletePredictionsExecuteThisMethod( final List<HashMap<String, String>> listOfHashmapsForAutocompleteTextview) {

        //making simple adapter for autocomplete textview
        String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, listOfHashmapsForAutocompleteTextview, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, from, to);

        actvLocations.setAdapter(adapter);

        /** autocomplete textview drop down items wouldn't show even after threshold set to 0 so .showDropDown() forces drop down items to show*/
        actvLocations.showDropDown();

        actvLocations.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View convertView, final int position, long arg3) {


                dismiss();

                final PlacesTask taskForLatLng = new PlacesTask(listenerForAutocompleteCompletedTask, "getPlaceLatLng");

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> clickedItem = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // set name of place for getting result back to header
                nameOfSelectedPlace = clickedItem.get("description");
                taskForLatLng.execute("placeid=" + clickedItem.get("place_id"));


            }

        });
    }
```

Here is the async task where the delay happends.
I've marked where the delay happends

```
 public class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private OnTaskCompleted listener;
String typeOfResult;
String url = null;

public PlacesTask(OnTaskCompleted callerListener, String type) {
    this.listener = callerListener;
    this.typeOfResult = type;
    switch (type) {
    case "getPredictions":

        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/";
        break;

    case "getPlaceLatLng":

        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/";
        break;
    }

    // this case is if we+re tying to get place name from latlng
    if (type.contains(","))
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/";

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
    Log.e("places task", "usao je tu");

    String data = "";
    String APIkey = "key=AIzaSyC5gP63PPD8CQLCXqbkZZf6XvOhZPnoe-s";


    /**
    //place type to be searched
    String types = "types=geocode";

    // our app didn't use any sensor to determinate the location
    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    */

    String parameters, outputFormat;

    // building paramters for search
    parameters = place[0] + "&" + APIkey;

    // output format
    outputFormat = "json";

    try {
        // fetching the data from web service
        data = downloadUrl(url + outputFormat + "?" + parameters);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        /**
         * activate error screen 
         */
    }

    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // create parser task to parse the gotten results
    ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask(listener, typeOfResult);

    // start the parsing
    parserTask.execute(result);
}

// private method used in the PlacesTask to download the data from the url
private String downloadUrl(String inputUrl) throws IOException{

    String data = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(inputUrl);

        //creating http connection to comunicate eith url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.e("places task", "3");

        /*
         * 
         * HERE IS WHERE THE DELAY HAPPENDS
         */

        **urlConnection.connect();**

        // reading from url
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        /**
         * activate error screen 
         */
    } finally {
        is.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    Log.e("places task data", data);
    return data;
}

 }
```

i didn't want to post ParserTask and GooglePlacesJSONParser so the question wouldn't be that long but if someone is intereested in those classes just add comment and i will update my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are experiencing a delay, possibly it is a network issue or something in the other classes.  But if you would like to try a library that provides a GooglePlaceAutoComplete widget, you could take a look at [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).

After the library is configured with your Google API key, you can add a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) element to your layout.  For example:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And then you can get the [Place](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Place.Prediction.html) that a user selects by setting an [OnPlaceClickListener](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.OnPlaceClickListener.html).

```
public void onPlaceClick(AdapterView<?> parent, Prediction place, int position) {
    /* do something with the Place */
}
```

Comment: thank you...will give it a try...but for anyone else, my strange problem went away itself so i guess this was some king of bug or something(wasn't network problem)

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation with this project. Just to let you know, the community tends to frown on a lot of self promotion.  You're doing it pretty well because you're not just answering questions related to the library you created; but don't be surprised if you receive downvotes for flags because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this link..

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

Onece I did used this Turorial... And Its working properly.